# Accidentally overwrote the "random" class in Python. Now unable to use any random. functions

Tags: python, random

While messing around with the random function in python I wrote a program which I saved as random.py. Once I wrote this program anytime I tried to import random and utilize any of its functions I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testrandom.py", line 3, in <module>
    print random.randint(10, 20)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

Any suggestions on how I might unoverwrite my random function?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you didn't save it in your Python installation's `Lib` directory (i.e., if you didn't physically overwrite the `random.py` that came with your Python), simply rename your `random.py`.

Comment: Rename your ``random.py`` to something not coinciding with the standard library?

Comment: And if you did... perhaps reinstall Python to a different location, and just copy the random.pyc / random.py files over to the `Lib` directory of your actual installation.

Comment: @Max_Wallace, in that case it will be easier to fetch ``random.py`` from the Python repository.

Answer (score 3):

The real `random.py` is still there, but Python is finding your `random.py` first.  Best solution is to rename your own module to something else, maybe `random_utils.py`.